# Ordenar array de forma descendente

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee

Quería implementar la siguiente función de Python en Java. La función toma como parámetro un array de elementos de tipo int y devuelva un nuevo array, con los mismos elementos que el original, pero ordenados en orden descendente, tal como en la función de Python mostrado a continuación

**Función en Python:**

```
def desc_sorted(lista):

    new_array = [0 for i in range(len(lista))]
    count = 0

    for e in lista:
        pos = 0

        while (pos < count) and (e < new_array[pos]):
            pos += 1

        for pos2 in range(count, pos, -1):
            new_array[pos2] = new_array[pos2 - 1]

        new_array[pos] = e
        count += 1

    return new_array
```

**Método en Java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ejercicio {

    public static int[] arraySorted(int[] array) {

        int[] new_array = new int[0 for (int i:array.length)];  // Error al definir el array

        int count = 0;

        for (int e:array) {

            int posicionamiento = 0;
            while (posicionamiento < count) && (e < new_array[posicionamiento]) {   // Error en el operador && (and)
                    posicionamiento += 1;
                    for (int pos2:(colocados < posicionamiento - 1)) {  
                        new_array[pos2] = new_array[pos2 - 1];

                    new_array[posicionamiento] = e;
                    count += 1; 
                    }
            return new_array;   
            }
        }   
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int[] valores = {3, 8, 14, 33, 77, 2};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arraySorted(valores)));
        }
}
```

Comment: Entonces, la versión en Java del algoritmo, ¿ha de realizar exactamente lo mismo que en Python? Con esto quiero saber si esa función que tienes en python que te ordena el array hay que "traducirla" a versión Java o no, si se puede hacer de otra manera (ahora estoy pensando en una más corta).

Comment: Hola Daenius, en efecto debo pasar la función de Python a Java. Dispongo de un algoritmo mucho más efeciente en Python para poder ordenar la lista pero se me pide "traducir" esa función. Gracias

Comment: Tengo dudas a la hora de interpretar tu código, puesto que no está escrito en Python, sino en "Java". Mal, pero está en Java. Si pudieras postear la función original te lo agradecería. A ver si así entiendo algo porque por ahora no sé quién es "colocados "

Comment: Adjunto la función de Python y marco en el método de Java los errores que tengo. Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta sería la "traducción" a Java de tu método en Python:

```
public static int[] desc_sorted(int[] array) {
    int[] new_array = new int[array.length];
    int count = 0;

    for (int e : array) {
        int pos = 0;
        while (pos < count && e < new_array[pos]) {
            pos++;
        }

        for (int pos2 = count; pos2 > pos; pos2--) {
            new_array[pos2] = new_array[pos2 - 1];
        }

        new_array[pos] = e;
        count++;
    }

    return new_array;
}
```

Comment: Iba a publicar la solución cuando te he visto, jaja. A mí no paraba de darme fallos por intentar usar objetos normales, no primitivos (Integer en vez de int, por ejemplo). Además, había preparado la lista de entrada, como él tiene. Buen trabajo compa ;)

Comment: Gracias a los dos, tenía una duda ¿porque como yo tengo el operador && no funcionaba?

Comment: no te funcionaba esa parte del while con los && porque te faltaban un par de paréntesis

Comment: ¿Tiene el operador que está entre paréntesis?

Comment: Fíjate, tenías esto puesto:  ```while (posicionamiento < count) && (e < new_array[posicionamiento])``` . Debería ser así:  ```while ( (posicionamiento < count) && (e < new_array[posicionamiento]))``` . La sentencia ```while()``` va con sus paréntesis de apertura y cierre. Si además vas a poner alguna operación entre paréntesis (como esos "a<b"), también debes cuidarte de poner los paréntesis respectivos.